# netsh advfirewall firewall dump gives no result

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, firewall

Props: Windows 7, Windows Firewall, my account is configured as administrator, CLI also as administrator

Because some rules entered via GUI did not work as expected, I've tried to check the rules on the command line.

However neither netsh firewall dump nor netsh advfirewall firewall dump do show more than some empty lines.

Are the GUI- and the CLI-Firewall two different things?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all profile=any type=static`

Comment: @Biswapriyo Your command gave indeed some output - comparable with the gui information (without the application path) It still didn't provide the complete picture, for example the default rules are missing. If you like you can make a complete answer, eventually explaining why my attempt didn't work and what the dump command is for.